# VIM replacement?

Tags: text-editors, editing, ide

What I do:

- PHP (Laravel 4, Yii, Drupal 7, bare)
- C/++ (GTK+, Qt 4/5)
- Ruby (+Rails)
- Perl (rarely, but still)
- Python2/3 (sometimes + Django)
- JavaScript (Node.JS, jQuery, Angular.JS)
- HTML
- CSS (+SASS, Less)

What I currently have: bloated VIM. I'm tired of it. Top 5 issues: single thread, crappy support for mixed modes, vimscript, lack of IPC, plugin conflicts, speed.

What I want: an editor or IDE capable to provide good support of all above. Even Java-based will do. Price < 300$ **It must be extensible.**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Eclipse 4.3.1 Kepler downloadable from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/.
I'm using it on a daily basis for:

- HTML5
- JavaScript
- CSS
- Sometimes PHP

There are at least plugins for C/C++ and PHP. You can easily install them via the Eclipse Marketplace.

Eclipse is Java based but better than its recent reputation. I consider it quick enough for productive work.

Eclipse is extremely extensible due to the OSGI/ Plugin architecture. For example, there  are plugins for all major SCM systems, also available through the Marketplace.